# How can a server find real client IP address?

Tags: javascript, ip-address, nat

I can only access the internet from my place from behind a NAT and a proxy. [This site](http://www.ipaddresslocation.org/) however also shows my machine's private LAN address, as well as my NAT's public address. They are apparently using javascript in the process, but I can only find code where they set the value, but not how they find it. So, how can we find out the private IP address of a client machine using javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you're behind *just* a NAT router? If you're behind a proxy, the proxy might well be adding an `X-Forwarded-For` header.

Comment: I'm behind at least one NAT, maybe more. The page does say transparent proxy detected, but the proxy address it shows is my public IP address, instead of the private proxy I use in the browser.

Comment: Yup, the proxy is sending `X-forwarded-for` in the header. Just checked using http://www.ericgiguere.com/tools/http-header-viewer.html.

Answer (score 3):

They're using Java for that:

```
<span class="pbb" id="lanip"><b>Router IP Address Testing...</b></span>
<script>
function MyAddress(IP)
{ document.getElementById("lanip").innerHTML = IP; }
</script>
<applet code="MyAddress.class" MAYSCRIPT width=0 height=0>
You Need To Enable Java For This To Work
</applet>
```

Comment: but I think this code only updates the value inside the html element that is displayed. That still leaves the question, how do they detect the ip address?

Comment: The MyAddress.class applet is doing it, which is Java code.  Disable Java and it likely won't work.  Here's a thread discussing the java code: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/Local.html