# Is it possible to get the Lan IP address with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm working with ASP.NET and I'm using `Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")` to get the Client's IP which seems to be like this `200.107.XXX.XXX`.

I'd like to know if is possible to get the "LOCAL OR LAN" Client's IP (i.e. `192.168.1.XXX`)

Comment: No such information exists as known to the server - that information is "lost" (it is never sent upstream).

Comment: Have a look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371020/how-can-a-server-find-real-client-ip-address?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that information is behind the corporate proxy and doesn't get surfaced to external systems.